# Recuperando objeto e setando em um modal

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, jsp

Como faço pra quando eu clicar no gatilho `editar`, um modal abrir com os dados de um objeto que eu previamente selecionei na tabela?

Segue meu código:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="background-color: white; padding: 10px;">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="#cadastro" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastro">
                        <span style="width: 20px; height: 50px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#editar" data-toggle="modal" class="edit" data-target="#editar">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="width: 20px; height: 50px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="width: 20px; height: 50px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="container" style="background-color: white;">
             <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
                     <tr onclick="toggle(this)">
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Papel</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.listaDeUsuarios}" var="usuario">
                            <tr id="row" onclick="changeColor();">
                                <td>${usuario.id}</td>
                                <td>${usuario.username}</td>
                                <td>${usuario.email}</td>
                                <td>${usuario.papel}</td>
                                <td>${usuario.status}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Ola Anderson, você poderia adicionar mais informações a pergunta e ser mais especifico em relação a sua duvida? Não estou conseguindo entender.

Comment: Eu possuo uma tabela com dados vindos do BD, e ao lado dessa tabela tenho uma tag html <a>, que é um gatilho para o modal de edição de usuário, que ao clicar nela esse modal deve se abrir com os campos preenchidos, correspondente a linha que eu selecionei, isso tudo sem fazer aquelas requisições com servlet. Pelo que eu pesquisar, dá pra fazer isso com Ajax. Mas eu não manjo nada.  Deu pra entender?

Comment: Poste o código na pergunta e mostre onde tem que fazer as modificações. Para editar a pergunta basta clicar no botão 'editar'. Leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para aprender a perguntar e como criar um exemplo.

Comment: O trecho de código tá no link.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta e coloquei o trecho de código nela.

Comment: Com mais informações na pergunta fica melhor para a comunidade te ajudar.